# Bound on the difference of two convergent infinite products

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, infinite-product

Let $(\alpha_n)$ and $(\beta_n)$ be two sequences of non-zero complex numbers such that the products $\prod_n \alpha_n$ and $\prod_n \beta_n$ are convergent. How to prove the following inequality?
$$
\left|\prod_{n\geq 1} \alpha_n - \prod_{n\geq 1}\beta_n\right|\leq\left(\prod_{n\geq 1}\max(|\alpha_n|,|\beta_n|)\right)\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{|\alpha_n-\beta_n|}{\max(|\alpha_n|,|\beta_n|)}.
$$

Comment: This follows from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2560702/42969, applied to $a_n = \alpha_n/\max(|\alpha_n|,|\beta_n|)$ and $b_n. = \beta_n/\max(|\alpha_n|,|\beta_n|)$.